# Горизонтальное меню с выпадающим списком, - подправить

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как, в приведенном ниже коде, сделать :

- выпадание вложенного списка по клику на элемент, который такой список имеет;
  (сейчас сделано по наведению курсора)
- по клику на конечный (по вложенности) элемент, чтобы все вложенности закрывались
  и можно было, например, вывести alert('дальше запрос');
- По клику на пункт меню 'верхнего уровня' он выделяется красным цветом, но при пере-
  ходе во вложенный список, такое выделение пропадает, - как бы зафиксировать ?

---

```js
var m = '';

document.getElementById('hmenu').addEventListener("click", menu_onclick, true);


function menu_onclick() {
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // ? как узнать на какой уровень меню кликнули :
  //   - 1й уровень (Text_1, Text_2 ..., Text_3)
  //   - 2й уровень (1, 2 ..., 3)
  //   - 3й (a, b, c)
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // ? как узнать на какой уровень кликнули :
  //   первый, или последний
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

  if ( target.style != m ) {

       target.style.background = 'red';                                                         
       if (m != '') {
           m.background = '';                              }  
  m = target.style;
  }  
}
```

```css
#menu {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
    background:#ccc;
}
#hmenu {
 width:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
}

#hmenu li:nth-child(1) {
 width:30%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) {
 width:40%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) ul a{
   width:150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) li ul {
   background:#c6c6c6;
   left:150px;
}

#hmenu li:nth-child(3) {
 width:30%;
}

#hmenu li{
 float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#hmenu li a{
 font-size:12px;
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 line-height:30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#hmenu li a:hover{
 background: goldenrod;
}
#hmenu li ul li{
    float:none;
}
#hmenu li ul li a{
    line-height:25px;
}
#hmenu li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #c3c3c3;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
#hmenu li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
#hmenu li ul li ul,
#hmenu  li:hover ul li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
#hmenu li ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="menu">
<ul id="hmenu">

 <li><a>Text_1</a></li>   
 <li><a>Text_2 ...</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a>1</a></li>
       <li><a>2 ...</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>a</a></li> 
                <li><a>b</a></li>
                <li><a>c</a></li>
            </ul> 
                </li>
       <li><a>3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>Text_3</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
</body>
```

---

*upd_1* уточню : 1-ый пункт 'хотелок' , чтобы открывалось по клику, но, по-прежнему закрывалось, если указатель мыши вышел за область выпавшего списка. Хотелось получить
максимум функционала не навешивая на каждый li по id.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы так , под себя сами адаптируете

```js
var menuElem = document.getElementById('sweeties');
var titleElem = menuElem.querySelector('.title');

titleElem.onclick = function() {
  menuElem.classList.toggle('open');
};
```

```css
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.menu .title {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu .title::before {
  content: '▶ ';
  font-size: 80%;
  color: green;
}
.menu.open .title::before {
  content: '▼ ';
}
.menu.open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Сладости (нажми меня)!</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Торт</li>
    <li>Пончик</li>
    <li>Пирожное</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```